# Why do these number theoretic bounds work?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

### Background

Consider the following function $P(n)$ which returns the smallest prime in the integer $n$ and $P(1) = 1$. Then, applying this to the first $n$ natural numbers we get a sequence like:

$$ 1,2,3,2,5,2,7,2,3,\dots,P(n) $$

Let $[x]$ be the integer part of $x$ and $p_j$ be the $j$'th prime. We define in the first $n$ terms of this sequence:

$$ \text{number of } p_i\text{'s} = \alpha_{p_i}(n) $$

Now, how many $2$'s are there in the first $n$ terms of this sequence?

$$  ( \alpha_2(n) - n/2 ) \leq 1    $$

How many $3$'s are there in this sequence? (We remove all the $2$'s and take a $1/3$'rd)

$$ ( \alpha_3(n) -  \frac{n - \alpha_2(n)}{3} )  \leq 1 $$

How many $5$'s are there in this sequence? (We remove all the $2,3$'s and take a $1/5$'th)

$$  ( \alpha_5(n) -  \frac{n - \alpha_2(n) - \alpha_3(n)}{5} )  \leq 1 $$

And so on ...

### Question

I have come about these formulas through observation. How does one prove they work always?

Comment: They don't always work. Your third inequality fails for $n=5$.

Comment: Your right I think a better inequality would be where the rhs is $1$

Comment: Btw you can get these explicitly: 
$$\begin{array}{}
\alpha_2(n)&=&\lfloor n/2 \rfloor\\
\alpha_3(n)&=&\lfloor (n+3)/6 \rfloor\\
\alpha_5(n)&=&\lfloor (n+5)/30 \rfloor+\lfloor (n+25)/30 \rfloor\\
\alpha_7(n)&=&\sum_{r\in\{7, 49, 77, 91, 119, 133, 161, 203\}}\lfloor (n+r)/210 \rfloor\\
\dots&=&\dots
\end{array}$$
See the OEIS sequence [A020639](https://oeis.org/A020639).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649964/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you edited the question, but they still do not work.

I found a counter-example for $p=11$ and $n=2196$.

$$\begin{align}
\alpha_{11}(n) -  \frac{n - \alpha_2(n) - \alpha_3(n)- \alpha_5(n)- \alpha_7(n)}{11} &=\\47-\dfrac{2196-1098-366-147-84}{11}&=\\\dfrac{16}{11}&\not \le 1
\end{align}$$

---

(For the original question:) They don't always work.

Your third inequality ($p=5$) fails for $n=5$, because:

$$
1-\dfrac{5-2-1}{5}=1-\dfrac25=\dfrac35\not\le\dfrac15
$$